# realloc fails in visual studio, but work using gcc (ntdll.dll)

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, malloc, realloc

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I have this code in C. When I run in VS it fails, but when I compile with gcc it runs perfectly. The error is this:

> Exception thrown at 0x779BE643 (ntdll.dll) in GestaoFinanceira.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000009.

This is my code.

I'm using this struct type:

```
struct budget {
    struct tm time;
    float valor;
};

struct geral {
    struct budget *b;
    int nelem_budget;
};
```

In main I call a function that will read from a file and save the values is the struct `g->b[]` as the number of elements in `g->nelem_budget`

```
int main() {
    struct geral *g = (struct geral *)malloc(sizeof(struct geral));

    readFileBudget(g);
    // just to check if the read was ok
    showBudget(g->b, g->nelem_budget);

    addBudget(g);
    // to check again if the item added is ok
    showBudget(g->b, g->nelem_budget);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is when the error appens:

```
void addBudget(struct geral *g) {
    int month, year;
    float value;

    // in the future, this values are to be an user input
    month = 5;
    year = 2015;
    value = 5000;

    printf("Month: %d, Year: %d, Value: %f\n", month, year, value);

    g->b[g->nelem_budget].time.tm_mon = month;
    g->b[g->nelem_budget].time.tm_year = year;
    g->b[g->nelem_budget].valor = value;

    g->nelem_budget++;

    struct budget *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = g->b;
    g->b = realloc(g->b, g->nelem_budget * sizeof(struct budget));
    if (g->b == NULL) {          //reallocated pointer ptr1
        free(tmp);
        printf("error-addBudget->realloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // just for debug
    printf("month: %d, year: %d, value: %f\n", g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].time.tm_mon, g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].time.tm_year, g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].valor);
}
```

I have an empty value at the end of the `g->b` array, that's why I first add the values, and then I call the `realloc`.

Comment: What is the value of g->nelem_budget?

Comment: Please add the code of the function `readFileBudget`

Comment: `realloc()` is too late.  Needs to be before `g->b[g->nelem_budget].time.tm_mon = month;`  OR  `realloc(g->b, g->nelem_budget * sizeof(struct budget));` is 1 element too small.

Comment: Pretty good attempt for a first question. Well done! You need to show where the actual contents of `geral` are initialized.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve] including the input files

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and see where it fails? This is one of the best methods to find errors in the code. And should be your first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reallocate first, then add a new element, not the other way round.

I don't like this

```
struct budget *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = g->b;
    g->b = realloc(g->b, g->nelem_budget * sizeof(struct budget));
    if (g->b == NULL) {          //reallocated pointer ptr1
        free(tmp);
        printf("error-addBudget->realloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

for a couple of reasons:

`realloc` should be called like this:

```
struct budget *tmp;

tmp = realloc(g->b, (g->nelem_budget + 1) * sizeof *tmp);

if(tmp == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    return 0; // return error code
}

g->b = tmp;
g->nelem_budget++;
```

Don't do `exit` in a function other than `main`. Instead of closing the program,
make `addBudget` return 1 on success and 0 on failure. The caller of `addBudget`
should decide what to do in case of failure, not `addBudget`. If you for example
put these functions in a library, your program would automatically end on error,
and that's sometimes something that you don't want to happen.

So, the function should look like this:

```
int addBudget(struct geral *g) {
    if(g == NULL)
        return 0;

    int month, year;
    float value;

    // in the future, this values are to be an user input
    month = 5;
    year = 2015;
    value = 5000;

    // reallocate first

    struct budget *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = realloc(g->b, (g->nelem_budget + 1) * sizeof *tmp);

    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error-addBudget->realloc\n");
        return 0;
    }

    g->b = tmp;

    // add new budget after reallocation
    printf("Month: %d, Year: %d, Value: %f\n", month, year, value);

    g->b[g->nelem_budget].time.tm_mon = month;
    g->b[g->nelem_budget].time.tm_year = year;
    g->b[g->nelem_budget].valor = value;

    g->nelem_budget++;

    // just for debug
    printf("month: %d, year: %d, value: %f\n", g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].time.tm_mon, g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].time.tm_year, g->b[g->nelem_budget - 1].valor);

    return 1;
}
```

and then in `main`:

```
int main() {
    // using calloc to initialize
    // everything with 0
    struct geral *g = calloc(1, sizeof *g);

    if(g == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not engough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // you should also check of readFileBudget
    // fails
    readFileBudget(g);

    // just to check if the read was ok
    showBudget(g->b, g->nelem_budget);

    if(addBudget(g) == 0)
    {
        free(g->b);
        free(g);
        return 1;
    }

    // to check again if the item added is ok
    showBudget(g->b, g->nelem_budget);


    // don't forget to free the memory
    free(g->b);
    free(g);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Also see: [do not cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

And error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.